# Linear Algebra--Is $H$ a subspace of $M$?

Tags: linear-algebra

So let's say we have H defined by $$
        H=\begin{pmatrix}
        x & z  \\
        0 & 2x \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ where $ x,z \in \mathbb{R}$

My question would be, is this a subspace of $M_{2x2}$? Here's my reasoning thus far:
I need to fulfill the three criteria for subspaces. Firstly, 0 needs to be in H. This can be easily found if $x=z=0$, right? Then, it needs to be closed under scalar multiplication. This can be easily shown since a real times a real is still a real. Wouldn't this, by the same reasoning, show that it is closed under addition as well? What's messing me up is that there is two of the same variable ($x$), in the matrix...

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean "where $x,z\in\Bbb R$"?

Comment: Either you change $\;a,b\;$ to $\;x,y\;$ or the other way around...or something...and you're on a very right track, indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contains $0$-matrix:

Set $x=z=0$.

Closure under addition:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
        x_1 & z_1  \\
        0 & 2x_1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
        x_2 & z_2  \\
        0 & 2x_2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        x_1+x_2 & z_1+z_2  \\
        0 & 2(x_1+x_2) \\
        \end{pmatrix} \in H$$

Closure under scalar multiplication:
$$k\begin{pmatrix}
        x & z  \\
        0 & 2x \\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        (kx) & kz  \\
        0 & 2(kx) \\
        \end{pmatrix} \in H$$

Comment: Thanks so much! So it is indeed closed under addition, thus it is a subspace. Got it!